# What would be the bet way to create a Front Row style menu?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

I'm working on a little program and would like to implement a menu in the style that is used in the Front Row application. I know this is an extremely open ended question but what would be the best way to go about creating such a thing?

I thought I could maybe use a NSTableView but from the looks of it, that seems overly complicated to get the scrolling to work correctly.

I'm wondering if I should just code my own menu view from scratch but wouldn't really know where to begin to start that.

Any thoughts or pointers would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides sample code that shows how to implement a fullscreen, list-like menu:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CoreAnimationKioskStyleMenu/Introduction/Intro.html

The code uses no AppKit classes (like NSTableView). The UI is made with Core Animation.

Another good core animation sample to create Front Row like Menus can be found in the following blog post:
http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/20080111